# Reactjs detect reload button click

Tags: reactjs, browser, reload

I'm trying to prompt a confirm alert when the user tries to click on the reload button of the browser, but it's getting prompted when the user loads the page for the first time and not when the click button is triggered.

I tried using different approaches but all seemed not to work:

```
     useEffect(() => {
    if (window.performance) {
      if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        window.confirm("This page is reloaded");
      } else {
        window.confirm("This page is not reloaded");
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

performance.navigation.type is depricated.

i also tried:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.BeforeUnloadEvent) {
      window.confirm("this may result in losing data");
    }
  },[]);
```

it didn't work either.

How can I fix it please?